# Adding to cloud search from celery doesn't work

Tags: django, celery, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm using `Cloudsearch` for searching on my website. When I try to add/remove items from the index, it works...as long as I don't do it as a asynch task in celery. If I do it outside of that it works perfectly. I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction?

My code is below:

```
from boto.cloudsearch2.layer2 import Layer2

@task
def add_employer(emp_id):
    conn = Layer2(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                  aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    domain = conn.lookup("mydomain")

    emp = # the value
    emp_map = {
        "name": emp.name,
        "id": emp.id,
        "url": emp.url
    }

    domain.layer1.sign_request = True
    doc_service = domain.get_document_service()
    doc_service.add(emp.id, emp_map)
    doc_service.commit()
```

is there something wrong with this code? I called the **exact** method with and without celery. It works consistently without celery and never with celery.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the manner in which it doesn't work in celery? What happens exactly? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Nothing as far as I know. No errors, but it definitely calls the method as I can tell from logs.

Comment: It sounds like you're sure celery is running the task so it seems like it must be either a) CloudSearch is never getting called or b) the wrong/empty values are being sent. Haven't used boto in a while but can you turn up the logging to trace and see if it's actually making a request to CloudSearch? I'm not sure where you sent `emp` but maybe it's not what you think it is within the task context so maybe you want to log that as well.